# swift: How to select content only in a cell?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `tableView` with an image in the table cell. When I click on a cell, the entire row is selected in gray. But I want to select only my image. How to do it?

Comment: You need to make the image clickable by adding tap gesture, or a simpler way is to take a button and make its appearance change on clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove gray color when you click on cell,write this code in 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' method of tableView:

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

If you want to click on image:
1.Use can put a button and above that put imageview.
2.Use 'touchsbegan:withEvent' method.
3.Use tap gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows. Set your table cell's selection style to **UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone**. This will remove the grey background highlighting. Then, to make the imageview highlighting work the way you want, instead of using the default UITableViewCell class, create a subclass of UITableViewCell and override the default implementation of **setHighlighted:animated** with your own implementation that sets the image view colors to however you want depending on the highlighted state.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Also set another control like `UIButton` same size as `UIImage`, and set background color of the `UIButton` for select / unselect the image.

Answer (score 0):

First, set your cell's `selectionStyle` to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`. This will prevent the gray color when you select your cell. Note that it won't remove the fact that the cell is selected, it'll just not show any feedback to the user. Keep that in mind if you're doing something in `tableView:didSelectRowAt:`

Second, add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `UIImageView`, and use it to perform any action when the user taps your imageView.

Comment: How exactly should I add UITapGestureRecognizer? I want to use `tableView:didSelectRowAt` but I need select only image.